"Correlation failed." after upgrading 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens' and 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt'
After upgrading packages Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens and System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt the service returns message "Correlation failed." when requesting /user/signin-oidc.
At the company we use keycloak as OIDC Provider.
I've tried different versions of the given packages (above vulnerable version 7.0.3) and upgrading also the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect as they are connected, but nothing seems to help.

a common problem is that you got some cookie issues, do check my blog post here https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/

This is unrelated to package versions. The keycloak settings were incorrect.
